# Add a new listener to existing Azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have created Azure application gateway with instructions in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/application-gateway-ssl-arm/). After completion I realised that it works with only HTTPS protocol. I want my website to work with both port, 80 & 443. I want to add a new listener. I was able to add a new listener on port 80 with corresponding rule to route to with that listener. THe first rule I created for HTTPS has following information for application gateway:

> "ProvisioningState": "Succeeded",
>   "Name": "rule01",

The rule for HTTP I have added is rule03 and it shows up in the appliation gateway without "ProvisioningState": "Succeeded". What I need to do to provision the rule to application gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add new port, new listener and corresponding new rule for port 80.

So from the link mentioned, you will need to create 2 ports, 2 listeners and 2 rules. and in the last step where you call New-AzureRmApplicationGateway, You will then need to pass 2 comma separated values to -FrontendPorts  -HttpListeners and -RequestRoutingRules .